# Can I use Clonezilla for backup without destroying what's already on the destination drive?

Tags: backup, usb-drive, clonezilla

I'm not sure I understand backups with Clonezilla. Will Clonezilla erase the destination (backup) disk as it creates a backup or will all the previously saved files be preserved on the backup disk?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes.

Clonezilla can operate in various modes. One of the modes is physical disk to image, which will write an image to a filesystem, without destroying anything present in the filesystem.

Other modes includes device to device, which *will* destroy the destinations content.

Comment: Agreed. I routinely use Clonezilla in this mode to send images to a directory on my file server.  Other files in the directory are unaffected.

Comment: @vidarlo: Is the "physical disk to image" mode the one discribed in here- https://clonezilla.org/show-live-doc-content.php?topic=clonezilla-live/doc/01_Save_disk_image

Comment: @BlueSkies, Yes, it is.